# Unable to connect to USB CDC device

Tags: kernel-modules, gentoo, devices

I have an 8 channel USB Relay board which I have connected via USB. The manual for the board states that:

> To use this product with Linux, USB CDC driver needs to be compiled in with the kernel. Fortunately, most Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Redhat, Debian etc..) has this driver pre-installed.
>
> The chances of you requiring to rebuild the kernel to include the USB CDC driver is very slim.
>
> When connected to a Linux machine, this product should appear as a serial port in the /dev directory. Usually the name of the device will be  `ttyACMx` or  similar. The  name  may be different depending on the Linux distribution you have.

In my case (running Gentoo), I did have to include the driver for USB CDC ACM to the kernel.

Plugging in my relay, I can see this using `dmesg`:

```
[76094.036163] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[76094.618717] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2a19, idProduct=0c02
[76094.618722] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[76094.618725] usb 4-1: Product: Numato Lab 8 Channel USB Relay Module
[76094.618728] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Numato Systems Pvt. Ltd.
```

Running `lsusb` I see `ttyACM0` appear. But sending command strings to it using `echo -ne 'string' > /dev/ttyACM0` has no effect. Additionally, `ls -al` of `/dev` shows that `ttyACM0` is not a character device file. In fact it shows:

`-rw-rw-rw-    1 root root            13 Nov  9 09:38 ttyACM0`

Is there some other driver or module which I need to enable? Why doesn't `ttyACM0` show as a character device? Is there something wrong with the way I am sending the commands to `ttyACM0`?

I have the relay running successfully on Windows after I install the Windows driver provided by the company. I can send it commands using PuTTY with no problems, but I can't find out what I haven't done right on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The device `/dev/ttyACM0` is a virtual serial port.  You'll need to use a terminal emulator to connect to it such as PuTTY, minicom, or screen.  With screen you would run something like

`screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600`

where 9600 is your baud rate. That will give you an interactive session to communicate with the board.

Comment: I've tried `screen` and PuTTY on Linux and no joy. I think an interesting thing is that it doesn't show as a character device when I `ls` /dev, where the other `tty*` show as either character or block devices.

Comment: That's because you just echoed something to /dev/ttyACM0 while it was not created, and _you_ created that regular file with echo. It clearly shows that either you don't have USB CDC support in your kernel, or you have to create such a node with `mknod` manually (old Linux), or your dynamic node manager - udev / mdev rules are out of date.

Comment: Also please edit your question and attach output of `lsusb`.

Answer (score 0):

> I did have to include the driver for USB CDC ACM to the kernel

I didn't write how you achieved it, but I had the very same issue as you, that is **Numato 8 Channel USB GPIO Module With Analog inputs** not listed in */dev/ttyACM0*
and I simply solved by:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi
```

At the end I have the /dev/ttyACM0 available for read/write.

Hope it helps to integrate the topic.